# iTextSharp 5.3.4:how to find and change the number of the page on which the link is directed from the PDF document?

Tags: itext

There is a problem:
Get references in PDF. Then get the page number on which the forward link. And move this link to 10 pages forward (for example, a link to the 5th page, and it is necessary, that it was the 15th).
I got an array of Destination, but how to get out the page number and change it, I do not know.
Tell me, please!
Code is:
`

```
Reader:=New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(OutFileName); 
PageCount:=Reader.NumberOfPages; 
For i:=1 To PageCount Do 
PageDictionary:=Reader.GetPageN(i); 
If PageDictionary.Contains(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.ANNOTS) Then 
annots := PageDictionary.GetAsArray(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.Annots ); 
For Each A In Annots.ArrayList Do 
AnnotationDictionary:= iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetPdfObject(A) As  
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary; 

////Make sure this AnnotationDictionary has a LINK and ACTION//// 

If (AnnotationDictionary.@Get(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.SUBTY PE).Equals(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.LINK)) 
And (AnnotationDictionary.@Get(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.A)<>N ull)  
Then 

////Get the Action //// 
AnnotationAction:= AnnotationDictionary.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.A ); 

////Get the Destination//// 
Dest_Array:=AnnotationAction.GetAsArray(iTextSharp.text.pdf. PdfName.D); 

End If; 
End For; 
End If; 
End For;
```

`